# Grails spring security denying access to other plugin

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

on a grails 2.4.3 project I'm using Spring Security Core plugin (2.0RC4) and another plugin call Feature Flipping.

All my controller are correctly secured and authentication is working without any problems.

The "Feature flipping" plugin expose a `/admin/feature` URI which allows user to switch through web.

I tried to configure static rules to permit only `ROLE_ADMIN` users to access this resource, but I'm still getting "Access denied" errors.

Any ideas ?

My staticRules:

```
'/admin/**':                  ['ROLE_ADMIN']
```

SpringSecurity debug log:

```
2014-10-28 17:15:47,805 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  - Request '/admin/features' matched by universal pattern '/**'
2014-10-28 17:15:47,806 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /admin/features at position 1 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2014-10-28 17:15:47,806 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository  - Obtained a valid SecurityContext from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT: 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@2116e65: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@2116e65: Principal: [REDACTED].security.UserDetails@f9520f8b: Username: pygillier; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@255f8: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 7FF242941B7F95FD17E97D8611B3A5CF; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER'
2014-10-28 17:15:47,806 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /admin/features at position 2 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'MutableLogoutFilter'
2014-10-28 17:15:47,806 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /admin/features at position 3 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter'
2014-10-28 17:15:47,806 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /admin/features at position 4 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2014-10-28 17:15:47,806 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /admin/features at position 5 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'GrailsRememberMeAuthenticationFilter'
2014-10-28 17:15:47,806 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /admin/features at position 6 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2014-10-28 17:15:47,806 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /admin/features at position 7 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2014-10-28 17:15:47,806 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /admin/features at position 8 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2014-10-28 17:15:47,807 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor  - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /admin/features; Attributes: [_DENY_]
```

Comment: Have you tried turning on Spring Security debugging? I can't emphasize enough how helpful this is in finding configuration mistakes and simple issues.

Comment: Enabled debug, still no clues on what's happening (see question for logs)

Comment: Well we can see from the log that you posted that the only attributes being returned for this URL are `_DENY_`. What is your configuration setting for `securityConfigType`? If you have none, the plugin will default to annotations, not the static rule map. You will need to specify that you would like to use the map.

Comment: The config setting is set to `securityConfigType.Annotation` (the default)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK got it,

I got confused as plugin's controller name & URL are different.

Plugin's controller name is `FeatureSwitchAdmin` and is mapped as `/admin/features`, in my staticRules I need to set

```
'/featureswitchadmin/**':              ['ROLE_ADMIN']
```

to get a valid credential.

(found solution with @rmlan clues and [official doc](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/requestMappings.html))

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to give this a shot based on the information that I've gotten from you already. If you are not specifying the `securityConfigType`, the Grails Spring Security plugin will default to using Annotations on controller classes. If this is the case (or you are explicitly using Annotations because you want to), you have a couple of options:

1. Set `grails.plugin.springsecurity.rejectIfNoRule` to false. This is not recommended as it potentially leaves other URLs not explicitly secured open for all. It might be ok for development, though.
2. If my assumptions are correct, you are probably using the incorrect static rules configuration. If you are using annotations, your static rules map must be defined as the configuration item `grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules`

As such, your configuration should probably look like this:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
    '/admin/**':                      ['ROLE_ADMIN']
]
```

For reference, this was the [line of code](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/933830f4bec5a206b513b5aee3ad7bbee257961f/src/java/grails/plugin/springsecurity/web/access/intercept/AbstractFilterInvocationDefinition.java#L99) that gave me a hint as to what was going on here. This tells me that the Spring Security plugin was unable to find the `'ROLE_ADMIN'` attribute that you had defined, and that `rejectIfNoRule` is set to true (which is the default).